# Unable to set worksheet names to variables, returns "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range"

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I am working on a project to filter a number of worksheets/columns.  First step is to identify the number of rows with values in the first column of the "Iris Data" worksheet, and build around that (as this will be used again with new data, deleted, and done again, etc.).  The code I have now does not work, and returns the error "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range".  Because many examples use a generic "Sheet1", I tried copy/pasting the same data into a new sheet named "Sheet1" and it was successful.  Unfortunately re-naming the sheets is not an option according to my supervisor.  I could probably get away with changing it a little bit, but not much.

So my question is, is this a naming issue with the space in 'Iris Data'?  Some other issue?

I tried changing to 'IrisData' or 'Iris_Data' and that is also returning RunTime error 9.  I also tried setting 'Sheet1' = "Iris Data", and that also returns RunTime error 9.

```
Sub Helping_Out_Alex()

Dim wb As Workbook              'identify source workbook
Dim IrisData As Worksheet       'identify Iris Data worksheet
Dim xlApp As Object             'tie workbook/worksheet into an object
Dim lastRow As Long             'identify numerical value for # of rows
Dim Sheet1 As String            'issue with spaces in name, work-around

Sheet1 = "Iris Data"            'Added this as a work around

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")    'set variable to object                                                         
Set wb = 
xlApp.Workbooks.Open("\\uk1.group.internal\data\PERSONAL\GorowsR\My 
Documents\Equiniti\Helping_Out_Alex.xlsm")       'set varaible to workbook

Set IrisData = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")           'set variable to first sheet

With xlApp                 'Example code                                                   
    .Visible = True        'Example code                                             
    .EnableEvents = True   'Example code                                           
End With                   'Example code                                           

With ActiveSheet
lastRow = IrisData.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row            'This is the variable I'm trying to define as a number so I know the range each time
    MsgBox "the value is" & lastRow
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I am not too certain about this, so not going to place this as an answer. Try `Set IrisData  = Workbooks(wb.Name).Sheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: @TimStack why dereference `wb.Name` from `Workbooks` if you already have `wb`? i.e. `wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")` is perfectly fine

Comment: You are creating an Excel Object using late binding, but then later on you use normal Excel properties. Where are you executing this code? Access? Word? Excel itself? Have you activated references to Excel Library?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon hence why I only post it as a comment. Something reminds me of a similar problem I had when I tried to do something similar. Can only remember I did something similar

Comment: If this code compiles, the Excel type library is referenced... `CreateObject` is completely unwarranted, and `xlApp` should be `As Excel.Application`.

Comment: @TimStack I mention it because I picked up the exact same missed opportunity in an otherwise perfectly fine recent answer of yours I upvoted a few minutes ago ;-)

Comment: first suggestion (from Tim) still returns 'Runtime error 9', and the reason I created an excel object was that I was having difficulty with this issue (I believe the issue was 'object required', so I decided to take a step back and pulled from an example that did it that way, and when I renamed one sheet "Sheet1" I could confirm that I was atleast getting to the correct file/sheet.  I am using excel 2016 and have "Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library" referenced

Comment: That's exaclly why ask, @MathieuGuindon. If OP is executing this code, let's say, in Access, and he uses objects like `ActiveSheet` without adding a reference to Excel Object Library, VBA in Access won't recognize `ActiveSheet` and will raise an error

Comment: And you get error 9 in line `Set IrisData = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") `?

Comment: foxfire and burns - yes, that is where the error is occurring

Comment: You're passing the *string ilteral* `"Sheet1"` to the `Worksheets` collection; did you mean to pass it the contents of the *variable* `Sheet1`? If so, I'd warmly recommend renaming that variable to `irisSheetName` or something similarly meaningful, assuming it's needed at all.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon makes sense. I am just too used to using the full `Workbooks(variable)` method!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
 Set IrisData = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

instructs excel to point to a sheet whose name (as shown in the excel tab at the bottom of the screen) is Sheet1. You can also point to a sheet by its code name (shown in the vbeditor project explorer window) so

```
Set IrisData = wb.Worksheets(Fred)
```

Or by it's index number, where the first sheet on the left is 1: so

```
 Set IrisData = wb.Worksheets(1)
```

Your problem seems to be that your sheet is actually called something like "Iris Data"
so you need either

```
   Set irisdata = wb.worksheets("Iris Data")
```

or (probably simpler) since you say it's the first sheet, just

```
  Set IrisData = wb.Worksheets(1)
```

Comment: This worked for me - more specifically changing to "Set IrisData = wb.Worksheets(1).  Thankyou!

Comment: @CircularReference note that of all options, that's the most frail one to use unless you're protecting the workbook structure such that the user can't reorder worksheets or insert new ones. If there's a worksheet ("tab") named "Iris Data" in that workbook, going by name would typically be more robust (although users can still rename sheets in an unprotected workbook). If going by name throws error 9, watch for leading or trailing spaces, and remove them.

Comment: I would agree with that, unfortunately I still cannot explain why I continue to get RunTime error 9 when I try to use "Iris Data", I've even tried copy/pasting from notepad so that the string should be the same when I rename the sheet, and put into the module.  Still get the error.  But this is for a co-worker that asked for help, so that's as much frustration as I'll do for them

Comment: In the vb editor, with the iris data sheet active in excel, in the immediate window type ? activesheet,name  That ought to display what excel thinks it's called. Alternatively, type Activesheet.name = "Iris Data" to rename it

Answer (score 2):

You can access a sheet by it's name (a string) or it's number (an integer). A blank in the name is not a problem, you can still access it by name.

All of this should do:

```
Const sheetName = "Iris Data" 
Set IrisData = wb.Worksheets(sheetName)
- or - 
Set IrisData = wb.Worksheets("Iris Data")
- or - 
Set IrisData = wb.Worksheets(1) ' This assumes that the sheet is the 1st sheet in  Workbook.
```

Maybe you struggle about

```
Sheet1 = "Iris Data" 
...
Set IrisData = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

There you set a (string) variable named `Sheet1` to the sheet name, but later you don't access the sheet that has the name that is stored in the variable, but a sheet that is named "Sheet1" (and, as it is missing, you get a runtime error 9). Just omit the quotes should do the trick (however, I would recommend to use a different variable name).

```
Set IrisData = wb.Worksheets(Sheet1)
```